# Which is better practice? Single query to SQL + Complex function OR Multiple queries, each serving a simple function

Tags: php, sql, laravel

In an app where I store SESSIONS during which USERS can buy one or more ITEMS, I am trying to track the sale status of each ITEM and aggregate them for the SELLER (in terms of both quantity and dollar value)

**Example of SELLER's dashboard**

```
*SESSION 1 (Revenues: $w, Pending receipts $x)*

ITEM A: SOLD 2, AWAITING PAYMENT 1

ITEM B: SOLD 1, AWAITING PAYMENT 0

*SESSION 2 (Revenues: $y, Pending receipts $z)*

ITEM A: SOLD 4, AWAITING PAYMENT 0

ITEM C: SOLD 0, AWAITING PAYMENT 0
```

I can imagine 2 ways to achieve this.

1. I make a relatively simple query but the result will likely mean I have a complicated function to process the results of that query before returning.
2. I make numerous specific queries, but I can break up the function into smaller pieces that *might* be re-usable for other parts of the app in future.

In principle, what I have read seems to suggest (2) is better coding practice. However, I have also read that processing in PHP is way lighter than the overheads of multiple SQL queries, hence my question.

Comment: Have you tried to write a query to do this in SQL.  Not sure how complex it is, looks like it should do it fairly easily.

Comment: Hi Nigel, I am doing this as we speak. Actually I made a mistake in my description and have corrected it. My issue is more of, is it better to make a simple general query and do the sorting of the results using PHP (which means a complicated function) or make several specific queries and keep my PHP functions simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to consider which solution is better we should first list the advantages and disadvantages of each approach.

## Single SQL query + complex PHP processing

#### Advantages

- The SQL is easier to maintain
- If requirements change, the database structure will not be affected as much
- Tests can be written without database interaction, making them faster

#### Disadvantage

- The PHP is harder to maintain
- Generally SQL performs better in processing data than PHP does
- Due to worse performance not as good with larger data sets

## Multiple SQL queries + simpler PHP processing

#### Advantages

- The PHP is easier to maintain
- Generally SQL performs better in processing data than PHP does
- Due to better performance also better with larger data sets

#### Disadvantages

- The SQL is harder to maintain
- If requirements change, the database structure will probably be affected as well
- Tests will probably have to interact with the database, which make them slower

## Conclusion

All in it probably comes down to your situation:

- How large is the data set you will be handling?
- How important is performance?
- How importing is testing (performance)?
- How often are requirements going to change?